# Website fell under the Google filters for inbound links

Tags: google, spam

We received a strange message on our support email.

> Message:Website http://fermersovet.ru/ fell under the Google filters
>   for inbound links. Google Webmaster shows that your site
>   www.mydomain.com has a link to our website. Remove Please link. Thank
>   you! Contact Mail:mendrelsdpoeldsa@mail.ru Name:SeoMaster Phone
>   Number:694

I looked up this issue and found some links regarding ["Smart Spam Bots"](https://www.optimizesmart.com/geek-guide-removing-referrer-spam-google-analytics/) - automated bots that might have scraped my Google Analytics ID from my website and are now sending traffic to this website.

My questions:
1. Is this what is happening? How else can I investigate this?
2. Should I be worried about this?
3. If this is not a Smart Spam Bot thing, what other protections can I take?

Comment: Personally, I'd ignore it and classify it as spam. Any SEO company sending this kind of rubbish isn't worth dealing with!

Answer (score 1):

Just having your GA ID isn't enough to compromise the site. There is the chance that the spambot is sending fake referrer information using your domain name, but that doesn't have anything to do with GA tracking code, and furthermore, it's out of your control even if they do.

If this email didn't come from Google, like @Matthew said, I'd classify it as SPAM and carry on business as usual.